# Generating Checklist from Joined Tables in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, checkboxlist

I am part of a team working on an MVC3 project.  None of us are (yet) MVC3 experts, so I'm not even sure how to ask the question properly.  I'll have to just dive in and hope it makes sense to you MVC-experienced folk.

We have an HTML data entry screen with 3 component sections: a large scrolling list on the left, a detail box in the center, and another scrolling list on the right.  The left-side list is a list of group codes and names drawn from a Groups table.  This is drawn by a partial view called _Groups.  The center area displays the detail fields for the currently selected group.  The right-side list is a scrolling list of person names.  The center and right are both drawn in a partial view called _GroupDetails.

The right-side list is what's giving us problems right now.  We have the Groups table, the Persons table, and an intersect table which stores a Group ID and a Person ID.  If a person belongs to a group, then there's an intersect record for that person-group pair.  If not, then there isn't.  We want to take the currently selected Group ID and use it for a query that draws all records from the Persons table and adds a boolean field.  The boolean field should be T if the person belongs to the currently-selected group, and F otherwise.  Then we want to display this as a checklist with the boolean field as the checkbox field and the name next to it.

What is the best way to do this?

-- Jon

---

Additional information, which I hope will be useful: Our data model for this view includes this List definition:

```
  public List<GlobalName> UserList { get; set; }
```

Is it possible to write a constructor for this list that includes a query, or a series of queries, that end up with the list containing the elements I want: a checkbox, the user name, and the user ID (primary key) with the checkbox set as described above?

Comment: Any code you are using as a starting point?

Comment: The relevant code and data classes are spread across half a dozen or more different files, so I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: This is a data extraction question, not specific to MVC.  What ORM are you using (EntityFramework, NHibernate, other) at the data layer to communicate with the database?  This is of course assuming you are using one...  You may want to retag your question based on this, MVC doesn't directly deal with how you retrieve your data, just how you represent it in model and view form.

Comment: I should clarify my comment:  *Half* of your question, namely data retrieval, needs to be accomplished using SQL queries. This may or may not be wrapped by an ORM, but is not part of MVC proper.  The second part of your question about how to model and render the retrieved data (as checkboxes, lists, etc) is what MVC is built for.  So asking again, what are you currently using to pull any of your data from the database?

Comment: PinnyM, we are using EntityFramework.  Back end is MS SQL Server 2008 R2.  One of our team has written a LINQ query that should retrieve the data we want.  Now we need to know how to get it into the format we want, the checkbox-list.

Answer (score 0):

MVC doesn't come with a CheckBoxList helper method built in as it does for SelectList. However, there are plenty of great extensions around so you don't need to reinvent the wheel.  You can check [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/292050/MVC3-Html-CheckBoxList-custom-extension), [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/miah/archive/2008/11/10/checkboxlist-helper-for-mvc.aspx), or [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2011/05/05/asp-net-mvc-implementing-checkboxlist.aspx) for some examples.

Using the MvcCheckBoxList extension, for example, you can do this:

```
// You'll need a view model
class GroupPersonsCheckListViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Person> Persons{ get; set; }
    public Group Group { get; set; }
}

// In your controller action:
var group = context.Group.Find(id); // assumes 'id' was passed to the action
var allPersons = context.Persons.OrderBy(person => person.Name);
var groupPersons = new GroupPersonsCheckListViewModel() { Persons = allPersons, Group = group };
return PartialView(groupPersons);

// In your partial
@Html.CheckBoxListFor("GroupPersons", 
    m => m.Persons,      // Collection of all persons
    p => p.PersonId,     // Person ID attribute
    p => p.Name,         // Person Name attribute
    m => m.Group.Persons // Collection of persons that are currently associated with the group
);
```

Comment: Thanks for this, PinnyM.  I've been off focusing on other things for the last couple of days, but I'm back on this now, and it looks like the above will be lots of help.